# Same colorbar for two scatterplots subfigures seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following code to produce seaborn scatterplots:

```
sns.set(
    rc={"figure.figsize": (12.27, 4.27), "figure.dpi": 300, "savefig.dpi": 300},
    font_scale=0.5,
    style="white",
    context="talk",
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2)

sns.scatterplot(
    data=df1,
    x="PCA-1 (morgan)",
    y="PCA-2 (morgan)",
    hue="uncertainty",
    palette="Set2_r",
    ax=ax[0],
)
ax[0].set_xlabel("PCA-1 (Morgan)")
ax[0].set_ylabel("PCA-2 (Morgan)")

norm = plt.Normalize(0, df1["uncertainty"].max(),)
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="Set2_r", norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])
# ax[0].get_legend().remove()


sns.scatterplot(
    data=df2,
    x="PCA-1 (morgan)",
    y="PCA-2 (morgan)",
    hue="uncertainty",
    palette="Set2_r",
    ax=ax[1],
)
ax[1].set_xlabel("PCA-1 (Morgan)")
ax[1].set_ylabel("PCA-2 (Morgan)")
# ax[1].get_legend().remove()


fig.colorbar(sm, ax=ax.flatten(), orientation="vertical")
```

The code above produces the following picture:

[image: Output1]

As you can see, the plot on the left has a colobar with a range (24, 48) for the hue I am using -- `uncertainty`. I used the `plt.Normalize` function to normalize from (0, 48). However, the plot on the right has a range (0.6, 1.6), but if you see it carefully, it is coloring the data points with the whole colormap instead of being constrained in the grey color area due to the range. How can I make the plot in the right color the points in grey because the range (0.6, 1.6) should be in that spectrum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding the parameter `hue_norm=norm` to each scatterplot above. That produced the following output figure:

[image: Correct Figure]

Answer (score -2):

You should explicitly specify `vmin` and `vmax` within your scatterplot. For your case,

```py
vmin, vmax = df1.uncertainty.min(), df1.uncertainty.max()

sns.scatterplot(
    data=df1,
    ...
    ax=ax[0],
    vmin = vmin,
    vmax = vmax
)

sns.scatterplot(
    data=df2,
    ...
    ax=ax[1],
    vmin = vmin,
    vmax = vmax
)
```

As noted in the documentation of [Seaborn Scatterplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html), any other parameters are passed to [Matplotlib scatter](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter) that can specify the `vamx` and `vmin` values, determining the range of values for the colors.

Comment: Thanks. Passing `vmin`, and `vmax` has no effect. I am researching why that is.